# Handsontable onchange event needs to change the value of the same cell itself not working while adjacent works

Tags: jquery, cell, onchange, handsontable

I have a handsontable structure as follows:

```
var container = document.getElementById('tableorder');
                        ordertable = new Handsontable(container, {
                            data: data,
                     colHeaders: ['Pdct', 'Notes', 'Qty', 'FQty', 'Fd Qty'],
                            columns: [
                                {data: 4, readOnly: false, type: 'autocomplete', source: prodnames, validator: product_validations, strict: true},
                                {data: 11, readOnly: false},
                                {data: 6, readOnly: false, type: 'numeric', format: '0.000', validator: qty_validations, allowInvalid: true},
                                {data: 18, readOnly: true, type: 'numeric', format: '0.000'},
                                {data: 19, readOnly: false, type: 'numeric', format: '0.000', validator: forward_validations, allowInvalid: true}
                            ],
                            minSpareRows: 1,
                            rowHeaders: true,
                            contextMenu: ['row_above', 'row_below', 'remove_row', 'undo', 'redo'],
                            colWidths: [250, rest, 100, 100, 100],
                            autoWrapRow: true,
                            autoWrapCol: true,
                            beforeRemoveRow: removerow_validation
                        });
```

Onchange of column **Fd Qty** as follows:

```
function forward_validations(value, callback) {
        var curdatatable = ordertable.getSourceData();

            if(value.toString().trim()==""){
                curdatatable[this.row][19] = 0;->not working
               // curdatatable[this.row][18] = 0;->working perfectly
                callback(true);
            }   
}
```

**What I am doing is If the onchange value is blank then the same column ie, 19th. Needs to be changed to 0**

In here the cell value needs to be changed and the onchange function happening cell is the same.

`curdatatable[this.row][19] = 0;` -> **not working**

but if I try

`curdatatable[this.row][18] = 0;` -> **Working**

Why it is happening like this?

How can change the value of cell if the onchange event happens on the same cell itself which is need to be altered?

Answer (score 2):

You're not really using an onchange event, you're using the validator function. Try using [beforeChange](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.21.0/Hooks.html#event:beforeChange) instead.

```
beforeChange: function(changes, source) {
  // changes is a 2d array like [[row, prop, oldVal, newVal], ...]
  if (changes[0][1] == 19 && changes[0][3].toString().trim() == "") {
    changes[0][3] = 0;
  }
  return changes;
}
```

Note you may need to loop through `changes` to handle when you change multiple cells at once (like copy and paste.)